# iPhone App Updgrade Query

Tags: iphone, sqlite, upgrade

I'm developing iphone app which take pictures and store it in iphone (within app folder) and picture name and other information stored in sqllite database. 
   If in future, I will release new version of iphone app then does it delete old pictures and update database?

Thanks,
Priya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your data will be intact after upgrade.

Of course you will have to properly migrate the database if you made changes.

Also, I would recommend using Core Data instead of SQLite directly.

Comment: Actually I have so many data which I need to store. That's why I choose sqllite. 
Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Core Data uses SQLite and offers better performance. Also, in my opinion, it offers easy data model management.

Comment: Can you give me any example or tutorial of CoreData?

Comment: Refer to the answers on the following questions for more about Core Data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581599/getting-started-in-core-data-for-iphone , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656476/new-to-core-data-for-iphone , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840634/core-data-vs-sqlite-for-sql-experienced-developers

Comment: Apple also has a lot of sample code on the subject, such as CoreDataBooks (formerly SQLiteBooks): http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/CoreDataBooks/index.html